# Showing couple of pictures in a page in matrix form

Tags: tables, graphics

I want to show 10 picture in a page in tabular form.
assume we can represent the page with 5 x 2 matrix and I want to show in each cell of this matrix one of my pictures.
Actually I'm new in LaTeX and I don't know what package of sample code I should use.

I would appreciate if you write a simple code or reference me a tutorial which it could help me.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Importing_external_graphics

Comment: And yes, you can put images into a tabular, and put a tabular into a figure.  Or just use `\begin{minipage}[c][0.2\textheight][c]{0.5\textwidth}`...